# Using Field Calculator for subtracting values with same ID in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, cursor, query, calculate-values

I have a line shapefile that used for some calculation.
One of the calculation is subtracting values with a same group ID.
The shapefile has a filed called `LineID` that consists of 2 lines with `Side` 1 and `side` 2.  Value of `A_path1` from `side` 1 should subtracted from `Side` 2 that have same `LineID` and stored in field called `Diff` in front of sid 1 or side 2 (doesn’t matter each).

How do I write a script with it with ArcPy in Python?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What error did you receive?

Comment: @vice I have tried any. I am not professional in python and arcpy.

Comment: You don't need to be a Field Calculator professional in order to make an attempt at code. Refusing to make an attempt to follow examples and make a best effort may convey an attitude that you either don't care or think the task beneath you, neither of which is going to help get the task completed.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively without scripting :

```
multiply side 2 value by -1 (field calculator)

summarize table asking the sum of you field, based on the LineID field

join the resulting table to you original table
```

Comment: thanks but I prefer to have it as a script.